# How to show the content of `[object Promise]` in koa2

Tags: node.js, ejs, koa, koa2

Here are my codes

```
  let list = ctx.get("list.json");
  ctx.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
            await ctx.render('index', {
                somecontent:onecontent,
                seconddata: list
            });
```

In `index.ejs`

```
  <%=seconddata%>
```

It shows the content `[object Promise]`, What do I do to show all datas of `seconddata`?

Comment: Could you please explain what you are currently doing?

Comment: @Vivasaayi I try to list all datas in `seconddata`, and I use ` <% seconddata.forEach(function(item){%>`, but it has no content.

Comment: This line looks not good: let list = ctx.get("list.json"); I hope you are trying to get the list, either from a remote url, or from a file. But this line is not doing it. If it does, you have to wait for the promise to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your code...

You could try `JSON.stringify()`

Also, since it looks like `list` is a Promise object, you might want

`let list = await ctx.get('list.json')`

so that `list` is an array of *resolved* Promises (which is likely closer to what you want).

Comment: I try to list all datas in seconddata, and I use ` <% seconddata.forEach(function(item){%>`, but it has no content.

Comment: Keep reading up on Javascript and whatever template library you are using. I'd also suggest using `console.log` on your server side to watch the data before it is rendered. Some of these functions and syntax are not doing what you expect them to do.